# Empty Queryset when using a Polymorphic Model from django-polymorphic and querying against the proxy model

Tags: python-2.7, proxy, django-1.11, django-polymorphic

I am using the django-polymorphic package:
https://pypi.org/project/django_polymorphic/

I was looking at the documentation for Proxy Models in the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

**Initial Setup** -  I tried the following with the regular django model class:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class MyPerson(Person):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def do_something(self):
        # ...
        pass
```

**Python Console:**

```
>>> p = Person.objects.create(first_name="foobar")
>>> p
<Person: Person object (4)>
>>> MyPerson.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<MyPerson: MyPerson object (4)>]>
```

However, when I tried using the PolymorphicModel from django-polymorphic on the Person Class and attempt the same commands, I get an empty queryset.

**Changed Person Model**

```
class Person(PolymorphicModel):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**Python Console:**

```
>>> p = Person.objects.create(first_name="foobar")
>>> MyPerson.objects.all()
<PolymorphicQuerySet []>
```

Shouldn't we expect the Queryset to contain the Person object we created?

My end goal is to create proxy models to register with two different Django Admin pages.

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to find a solution? Or an explanation to why this happens?